# nginx virtual hosts not working after enabling IPv6

Tags: nginx, ssl, virtualhost, ipv6

I've just enabled IPv6 on my nginx 1.8.0 webserver based on Debian Jessie. To do this I've edited my Virtual Host-Config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [2001:1608:10:160:34::2]:80;
    server_name dominicpratt.de www.dominicpratt.de;
    return 301 https://dominicpratt.de$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    listen [2001:1608:10:160:34::2]:443;
    server_name dominicpratt.de www.dominicpratt.de;
    root /var/www/dominicpratt.de;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/dominicpratt.de_access.log;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/dominicpratt.de/combined.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/dominicpratt.de/wildcard.key;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-www.sock;
            fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
            expires 365d;
    }

}
```

Now my website dominicpratt.de is working just fine, but my subdomains aren't. They're redirecting to dominicpratt.de - example: rss.dominicpratt.de and the following config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [2001:1608:10:160:34::5]:80;
    server_name rss.dominicpratt.de;
    return 301 https://rss.dominicpratt.de$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    listen [2001:1608:10:160:34::5]:443;
    server_name rss.dominicpratt.de;
    root /var/www/rss.dominicpratt.de;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/rss.dominicpratt.de_access.log;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/dominicpratt.de/combined.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/dominicpratt.de/wildcard.key;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-www.sock;
            fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I'm not able to reach https://rss.dominicpratt.de and all the other subdomains. If I delete or comment out the IPv6-listen-lines in the server-block it works just like it should to.

Comment: It's usually bad idea to mix up `listen` directives with and without IP address. Also you've got different IP addresses in different server block.

Comment: Common way is to have one `listen` directive for a port per block: `listen [::]:80 ipv6only=off;` or `listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=off;` are common. See http://nginx.org/r/listen

Comment: If you want to use the same IPv6 address for all `server` stanzas, then the suggestion by @AlexeyTen sounds right. If you have more IPv6 addresses and want to take advantage of them by assigning different IPv6 address to each `server` stanza, then I think you can use `listen 0.0.0.0:80` and `listen [2001:1608:10:160:34::2]:80` in the first `server` stanza, and let the next be the same except from the IPv6 address being different.

Comment: I'm not seeing a redirect to dominicpratt.de - I see the tiny tiny rss login page. Make sure you haven't done something like leaving the wrong IPv6 address in /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx 1.8.0 had a bug[1] (fixed in 1.8.1) that enabled SPDY/h2 by default. With http/2 browsers try to open only one connection per server[2]. Firefox does this in a very aggressive manner[3]. It reuses IPv6-Connections across hostnames even if the IPv6-Adresses don't match (but IPv4-addresses match and certificate matches). With wildcard-certificates this may lead to the observed problem[4] where content of the wrong domain is served.

The browser in this case is trying to unshard the subdomains to optimize speed wrongly thinking the different subdomains were only put in place to optimize speed in http/1 (i.e. by using stattic1.example.com and static2.example.com to get more server connections in parallel).

The Problem can be solved by A) using different certificates for the domains, by B) using the same IPv6 address for the domains or C) by sending http status code 421[5] for the misguided requests.

- [1] http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES-1.8
- [2] https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#reuse
- [3] https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1190136
- [4] https://www.trullala.de/firefox-http2-ipv6-pitfall/
- [5] http://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#MisdirectedRequest

Comment: Or you could upgrade nginx.

Comment: In that case the problem is that you are using a wildcard certificate where you should have been using two separate certificates. Even with plain old HTTP/1.1 over SSL you would be vulnerable to MITM-attacks redirecting traffic for one of your servers to the other which would serve different content but with the same certificate.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `ipv6only=on` to your `listen` directive for IPv6 address like so:

```
listen [2001:1608:10:160:34::5]:80 ipv6only=on;
...
listen [2001:1608:10:160:34::5]:443 ipv6only=on;
```

The fact that you specified IPv6 address in listen directive does not turn off IPv4 by default.

Comment: I think the `ipv6only` setting only makes a difference if the address is `::`

Comment: This is correct, as per documentation "whether an IPv6 socket listening on a wildcard address [::] will accept only IPv6 connections" which is to be expect since there can't be an IPv4 socket with an IPv6 address ^^